# How do I determine which element has specific classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML structure:

```js
$("li").on("click", function(){ 
  // I need to remove active-class form current element
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
li:hover{
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Numbers:

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li class="active">Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

In the code above, when you click on the content of `<li>` tag, `active` class will be added to that element. Now I want to detect whether `active` class is on which element? and remove that class from it first *(`.removeClass()`)*, and then add `active` class to clicked element. In other word, I need to make it (`active` class) unique.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.siblings()`

```js
$("li").on("click", function(){ 
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
li:hover{
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li class="active">Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use this:

```
$("li").on("click", function(){ 
  $('li.active').removeClass('active');
  // I need to remove active-class form current element
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

First remove the active class from previous active element: `$('li.active').removeClass('active')`, then simply update the clicked element.

Answer (score 2):

Use not() to select all active class li's  except the clicked one and remove its activ clas

```
$("li").on("click", function(){ 
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("li.active").not(this).removeClass('active'); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("li").on("click", function(){ 
   $("li.active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```